# Taking the value of the node above in xsl for-each loop

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, iteration

Given the following XML format:

```
<Book>
  <ID>160-2<ID>
  <Author>
    <Name>Mark Polo</Name>
  </Author>
  <Cost>
     <Shop>BookLover</Shop>
     <Value>2000</Value>
  </Cost>
  <Cost>
     <Shop>MakingBooks</Shop>
     <Value>1500</Value>
  </Cost>
  <Cost>
     <Shop>AppleBooks</Shop>
     <Value>3000</Value>
  </Cost>
</Book>
```

Need to make following structure:

```
<BookCost>
  <ID>160-2</ID>
  <AuthorName>Mark Polo</AuthorName>
  <Value>2000</Value>
</BookCost>
<BookCost>
  <ID>160-2</ID>
  <AuthorName>Mark Polo</AuthorName>
  <Value>1500</Value>
</BookCost>
<BookCost>
  <ID>160-2</ID>
  <AuthorName>Mark Polo</AuthorName>
  <Value>3000</Value>
</BookCost>
```

Element Book and Cost are unbounded. I guess I should go into the loop xsl:for-each select="Cost", but is there any possible way to get ID and shop name, if if the number of Book and Cost elements is multiple and unknown? Here is the example of xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
        <resultDocument>
        <xsl:for-each select="//document/Book/Cost">
        <BookCost>
        <ID>??</ID>
        <AuthorName>??</AuthorName>
        <Value>
        <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
        </Value>
        </BookCost>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </resultDocument>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you add your XSLT so we can see the `xsl:for-each`?

Comment: If you select `Cost` in an xsl:for-each, you can get the ID and author name by going back up the tree using `..`. Example: `../ID` and `../Author/Name`.

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: Sure, added an example of xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving comment to answer...

If you select `Cost` in an `xsl:for-each`, you can get the ID and author name by going back up the tree using `..` (which selects the parent and is abbreviated syntax for `parent::*`).

Examples:

`../ID`

and

`../Author/Name`

Answer (score 2):

Going up and down the tree is possible, but inefficient. A better method would store the parent values in variables once and use these at the child level:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/document">
    <resultDocument>
        <xsl:for-each select="Book">
            <xsl:variable name="id" select="ID" />
            <xsl:variable name="authorName" select="Author/Name" />
            <xsl:for-each select="Cost">
                <BookCost>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$id"/>
                    <AuthorName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$authorName"/>
                    </AuthorName>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Value"/>
                </BookCost>
            </xsl:for-each>         
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </resultDocument>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Using variables looks great! Thanks!